# Unclear benefit of "setLoading" state in React axios

Tags: reactjs, use-state

[image]

Hey, could anyone tell me what the state loading does?
What do we aim to achieve using the "setLoading(true)" wihtin axios?
Thank you!

Comment: Usually you’d use a Boolean variable like that to show a loading indicator while the request resolves. If you aren’t using it why are you adding that variable?

Comment: Just a note. set-loading should be triggered right before the backend request, not after.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A loading state is generally used to conditionally render a loading indicator, or similar, while data is being fetched. You can also conditionally hide empty state while it is not populated yet.

Also, generally you would toggle an `isLoading` state `true` immediately prior to making the asynchronous request, setting it back to `false` when the fetch is complete and you've enqueued a state update.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]); // no data yet
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  axios.get("......")
    .then(data => {
      setData(data); // update state with response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // handle any errors/rejected Promises
    })
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false)); // complete loading success/fail
}, []);

if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;

return data.map(.......);
```